# Retrieve extension version in php

Tags: php, php-extension

Is it possible to get extension version in php?

`get_loaded_extensions` returns only loaded extentions names, but not versions :(

Comment: Only if an extension provides a way of querying its version.

Comment: @Jon All extensions provide a way of their version being queried: `$version = phpversion("extensionName");`.

Comment: What is meant by extension? Extension to Apache, PHP, or browser?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I believe this is what you're looking for:

`$version = phpversion("extensionName");`

[More information](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpversion.php)

Comment: note that this does not work with `curl` & `mcrypt`(both return `false`), seems to have been there for a long time: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=40582, no answer found.

Comment: also doesn't work for PCRE (see link in comment above), but you can check the constant `PCRE_VERSION` for version info

Comment: OpenSSL is an interesting case, Neither this method nor the Reflection method below return any version information. But OpenSSL instantiates the constants OPENSSL_VERSION_TEXT and OPENSSL_VERSION_NUMBER. Clearly there is no standardized way of getting versions from extensions.

Answer (score 49):

At the command line, where *extension* is the extension name.

`php --re extension | head -1`

If unsure of the extension name, list extensions with `php -m`.

Comment: This is not working if you try to detect the version of an extension.dll what is not compatible with your php version

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionextension.getversion.php

```
<?php
    $ext = new ReflectionExtension('mysqli');
    var_dump($ext->getVersion());
?>
```

Comment: Provide some explanation

Comment: This returns the same version information as phpversion($extension). I checked 58 extensions, of which 30 returned version information.

Comment: Under PHP 7.1-7.3 (more?), both phpversion("extension name") and ReflectionExtension return the PHP version (not the extension version). I guess this is something like the wrapper version, which gets automatically bumped up during release. Not that useful. It does check whether the extension exists (if it doesn't exist it returns null)

Comment: Correction, it returns false.